# Using same aar library in several projects

Tags: java, android, gradle, aar

There is `library-x` which is assembled into `aar` file. There're two projects: `project-a` and `project-b`. Both of them use `library-x`. But at the same time `project-b` is used inside `project-a`. So when I'm trying to assemble `project-a` I get `duplicate entry` exceptions:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForMock'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/libraryx/BuildConfig.class
```

I understand why it happens: because there're same classes of `library-x` in both projects. But how to solve it?

Comment: probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612871/using-same-aar-library-in-several-projects